# How can I limited that the web api is respond to the special client only?

Tags: authorization

Let say I am creating a web api for my client to connect, the web api is public on the web. But I only allow the special client(for example, an iOS or Android) can connect it... others, is not allow to call the web api, even their params are correct? Is there any way to do so? Thanks.